# How to override global style from a child component and scope the change only under that component in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components

I have declared some css styling in global style.css file which is src/style.css in my angular project. In one of my component I want to override some styling and scope it only for that component. Currently, I can able to do that by using ::ng-deep, but, problem is, while I am changing global style from my child component using ::ng-deep it also alter the styling in global.scss as a result rest of my component also affecting for this. So what I want is, when I am changing this global style from that child component I just want to scope that change under that component.

The CSS class I declare in Src/Style.css is:

```
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

I applied following attempts which did override the global styling, however, it also keep the change as a result other components also get affected by that change.

**Attempt 1:**

I apply `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component and apply following in component scss file:

```
.main-content {
  padding: 24px 0px !important;
}
```

It worked, means, it does override the global style but the change doesn't scope only for this component.

**Attempt 2:**

I remove encapsulation for the component and apply ::ng-deep like below:

```
::ng-deep .main-content {
   padding: 24px 0px !important;
}
```

it also do the same as attempt 1.

**Attempt 3:**

I also found that if I use ::ng-deep with :host it scope the change only for that component. However, I couldn't able to make it working when I am using :host. Like the following piece of code doesn't do anything for my case:

```
:host ::ng-deep .main-content {
  padding: 24px 0px !important;
}
```

In this situation, how can I achieve overriding global css and scope it only for that component?

Comment: Hello. Do you have the stackblitz link that proves that #3 is not working?

Comment: Sorry I don't have

Comment: CSS does not have a possibility to propagate styles up the tree, so (assuming `.main-content` is located above `:host`) there's no way #3 will work.

One possible solution would be to introduce a service with a flag — the root component would then conditionally apply a class based on the flag (`<div class="main-content" [class.main-content-condensed]="service.isCondensedView">`), and the `:host` component would set the flag to `true` on init and back to `false` on destroy.

Comment: it seems author is interested in overwriting styles "under" component, nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use Javascript.

We assume that the main-content have id="main".

You just need to add this code in ngOnInit of the child component:

```js
element: HTMLElement;

constructor(
  .
  .
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.element = this.document.getElementById('main');
   this.element.classList.add('your-custom-class');
}
```

And in the ngOnDestroy() remove this class:

```js
ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.element.classList.remove('your-custom-class');
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved? any question?

Comment: Yes this answer solved my problem :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using .main-content in multiple places.

If that's the case, I'd avoid using ::ng-deep at all, removing it from your child component.  Instead, I'd just add a new class to your .main-content element as follows:

```css
.alternate-content {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content alternate-content"></div>
```

You won't need to use !important here either, because the selector is more specific.

Alternatively, you can omit .alternate-content, if you can define a selector that is specific to the instance of .main-content in your component:

```css
.my-component-container {
  .my-component-panel {
    .main-content {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't get your answer fully, you meant add another class in global scss and apply it with the main-content? By this both class styling will be applied isnt it? But i want only one class should be apply at a time

Comment: No.  You would define the .alternate-content class in your component's .scss file.  Alternatively, you don't necessarily need to add the additional class, as long as you can define a selector in the component's .scss that is specific only to that component.  I'll update the answer to illustrate this.